# How can I create a boolean empty column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I want to add an empty boolean column to a given pandas dataframe.
For now I have done this (df being my dataframe):

```
df["empty_bool_col"]=None
df["empty_bool_col"]=df["empty_bool_col"].astype(bool)
```

Then, my column looks like this:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: empty_bool_col, Length: 4, dtype: bool
```

This does not convey the fact that some values may be missing, and that the column is in fact, empty. Is it not possible to get an empty column of boolean type inside a pandas dataframe?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  Boolean stores either True or False, a work around would be to change it to int column with 1, 0 or NaN.

Comment: Like Scott said, pretty sure this is not possible since Booleans are two constant python objects. The solution @ScottBoston suggested is a good workaround. Or if you are not going to use it for calculation, use numbers as strings: '1', '0' and empty string ''

Comment: You can fix it by convert to object , then mask the nan .......however , this will mess up your data type ..

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy.nan and 'boolean' type. It's work well for me.

```
import numpy as np
df["empty_bool_col"]=np.nan
df["empty_bool_col"]=df["empty_bool_col"].astype('boolean')
```

Comment: This sets every value to True, which does not address the OP's request for an "empty" column of boolean type.